# file upload from a new window opened using javascript does nothing

Tags: javascript, forms, post, file-upload, new-window

I have a client side javascript application. At a specific trigger, the application creates a new window using window.open(). In the new window, I want to allow the user to upload a file. For this, I have provided a form in the new window. The form is fairly simple - an input element of type "file" and a submit button. When the user clicks the 1st element, the pop-up correctly appears to allow selecting a file from the local filesystem. After the user selects the file, when I click the submit button, the window simply goes blank; the file contents do not get uploaded to the server. The server is a proprietary server using port number some proprietary port number (say 30000) for the http sessions with the clients. 
If I use the same javascript within the original window (i.e. without opening a new window) the file contents are getting posted and I see the server receiving the file contents. But if executed in a new window, nothing happens. The script (core part required for this functionality) is below.

```
myWin = window.open("", "", "width=400, height=400,scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes");

var myForm     = myWin.document.createElement("form");
myForm.action  = "";
myForm.method  = "post";
myForm.enctype = "multipart/form-data";
myWin.document.body.appendChild(myForm);

var myInp = myWin.document.createElement("input");
myInp.type = "file";
myInp.name = "filename";
myForm.appendChild(myInp);

var myBtn = myWin.document.createElement("input");
myBtn.type    = "submit";
myBtn.value   = "Upload";
myBtn.onclick = "Upload";
myForm.appendChild(myBtn);
```

Any idea what could be wrong? Are there any additional settings I have to do for the new window? I am suspecting may be the new window does not do the upload because the same-origin-policy is not maintained when the new window is opened - maybe the proprietary port number is not copied from the first window into the 2nd; but - I am not sure; and even if I was I don't know how to get around this. I will be grateful for any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're opening a blank window, that does not have an URL. Moreover, you're setting the action on the form as blank, which means submitting the form to the same page.

Having a blank URL in the pop-up, there is no page to submit to, so the form goes to nowhere.

Try one of the following:

1. Set the action string to the actual page you want to submit your form to (This is not cross-origin controlled). Example: `<form action="submit.php">`
2. Set the URL of the pop-up by actually opening a page that contains the form instead of creating it with JavaScript. It will have the same look / size, but it will get submitted right. Make sure you either handle form submissions on that page (if it's PHP or ASP), or set the action properly (as described before)